# ROS Answers SE migration: ros commands

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually i have given rosnode list
ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!
will u please help me how to tackle this... but yesterday it executes correctly

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51523/ros-commands/) by [Abinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3901/abinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must have had roscore running, yesterday.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6